# How do you get authentication bearer using a username and password for the Azure Blockchain Workbench using ADAL in python?

Tags: python, azure, adal, azure-blockchain-workbench

I have been trying to perform some contracts on my Azure Blockchain Workbench from Python. I have been unable to figure out how to use this method. adal.acquire_token_with_username_password()

I need to first perform an Authentication to get the bearer for making further API calls.
It works perfectly using this `context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(client_id,client_id,client_secret)` 
However, the above bearer token isn't associated with any registered user.

however, to perform admin tasks like adding new users, one has to obtain the bearer for the admin account. So I thought of using `acquire_token_with_username_password()` so that I get the admin account's bearer.

```py
import adal
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.api_client import ApiClient
context = adal.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/kumarshobhit98outlook.onmicrosoft.com/",api_version=None)
client_id="c62087b9-cfed-4105-a9c2-4fd3953ceed5"
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource='https://graph.windows.net',username="shobhit@kumarshobhit98outlook.onmicrosoft.com",password="password",client_id=client_id)
print(token['accessToken'])
```

I guess maybe the Resource parameter is incorrect. I do not know what the parameter means. 
Also this is there error that i get,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/codefundo2019/voting-system-blockchain/contractsShobhit/python/regVoter.py", line 8, in <module>
    token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource='https://graph.windows.net',username="shobhit@kumarshobhit98outlook.onmicrosoft.com",password="Alonso123",client_id=client_id)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 164, in acquire_token_with_username_password
    return self._acquire_token(token_func)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 128, in _acquire_token
    return token_func(self)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\authentication_context.py", line 162, in token_func
    return token_request.get_token_with_username_password(username, password)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 281, in get_token_with_username_password
    token = self._get_token_username_password_managed(username, password)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 177, in _get_token_username_password_managed
    return self._oauth_get_token(oauth_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\token_request.py", line 112, in _oauth_get_token
    return client.get_token(oauth_parameters)
  File "C:\Users\SHOBHIT KUMAR.SHOBHIT-PC.000\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\adal\oauth2_client.py", line 289, in get_token
    raise AdalError(return_error_string, error_response)
adal.adal_error.AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: 2492ffdd-46e6-4edb-a412-47eefd200a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 2bbb1de3-b0b8-4510-b723-237e2faa7163\r\nTimestamp: 2019-08-09 06:50:11Z","error_codes":[7000218],"timestamp":"2019-08-09 06:50:11Z","trace_id":"2492ffdd-46e6-4edb-a412-47eefd200a00","correlation_id":"2bbb1de3-b0b8-4510-b723-237e2faa7163"}
```

I do not understand why is it asking for a client_secret for the username password method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, to perform admin tasks like adding new users, one has to
>   obtain the bearer for the admin account.

This is not correct. The token permissions is not related to the account, but the permissions you granted to the application. For example, if you want to call [add new user api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You will nedd `User.ReadWrite.All` permission.

[image]

Go to Azure portal->Azure Active Directory->App registrations->find your app->Api permissions->add a permission->Microsoft Graph->Application permissions->choose `User.ReadWrite.All` permission->Grant admin consent.

> I guess maybe the Resource parameter is incorrect. I do not know what
>   the parameter means

This is the App ID URI of the target web API (secured resource). It may also be an external resource like https://graph.microsoft.com. You set it with `https://graph.windows.net`. Then you will only be able to call [Azure AD graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api).

> I do not understand why is it asking for a client_secret for the
>   username password method.

You need to treat the application as public client.

[image]